# Eigenvalues of an n x n symmetrical matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, contest-math, determinant

I'm attempting to solve problem B5 from Putnam 1999:

**For an integer $n \geq 3$, let $\theta = \frac{2 \pi}{n}$. Evaluate the determinant of the $n \times n$ matrix $I + A$, where $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix and $A = (a_{jk})$ has entries $a_{jk} = \cos(j \theta + k \theta)$ for all $j,k$.**

I don't want to look at the official solution as I want to go through the problem myself. I calculated the determinants for $A_3$ through $A_6$, and they were $-1.25, -3, -5.25, -8$. The matrices are also all symmetrical, which is obvious from the definition of $A$. Here is $A_3$, for example:

\begin{bmatrix}
-0.5 & 1 & -0.5\\
1 & -0.5 & -0.5\\
-0.5 & -0.5 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

I found the pattern $\det(I_n+A_n)=1-\frac{n^2}{4}$, and as most mathematical competitions go, this is surely the solution, however, I now have to prove it. My teacher suggests using a proof by induction, however, I lack a general formula for the determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix.

In looking for one, I have come across the fact that the product of the eigenvalues of a matrix is equal to its determinant. I have also found out that symmetrical matrices have exactly $n$ eigenvalues and there exists a set of eigenvectors that are mutually orthogonal.

How do I calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of an $n \times n$ matrix in this form?

Comment: What happens when you cofactor expand the determinant for $n+1$? Doesn't it at least partially involve the determinant for $n$?

Comment: Thank you for the idea, let me try.

Comment: One possible approach (but I don't know if it works or not): let $v=(e^{i\theta}, e^{2i\theta}, \ldots, e^{in\theta})^\top$. Then $2A=vv^\ast + \bar{v}\bar{v}^\ast$. Since $A$ has rank 2, you may try to find its two nonzero eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ and get $\det(A)=(1+\lambda_1)(1+\lambda_2)$.

Comment: @user1551 I don't fully understand the notation before you state that $A$ has rank 2.

Comment: @Ian - I've tried, however, I cannot simplify the remaining terms after going through the $n+1$ step and completing the induction.

Comment: @user1551, your idea is great for this problem. but there are minor typos. We have $2A = v v^T + \bar{v} \bar{v}^T$. Also, $\det (I+A) =  (1+\lambda_1)(1+\lambda_2).$.

Comment: @user1551, In fact, we have $\lambda_1= \frac n2$, $\lambda_2 = -\frac n2$.

Comment: @i707107 can you explain the notation you use after $2A=\cdots$?

Comment: @michaelwm It is the product of matrices $v$ and $v^T$. Note that $v$ is a column vector and $v^T$ is a row vector.

Comment: @i707107 what is being added to $vv^T$? What vectors are you referring to there?

Comment: @michaelwm $\bar{v}$ is obtained by taking complex conjugates of each component of $v$.

Comment: @i707107 ah, thank you. I will try to finish this problem. Also - the eigenvalues you calculated do have the product $(1+\frac{n}{2})(1-\frac{n}{2})=1-\frac{n^2}{4}$, so I believe I am on the right track. Now I have to find your eigenvalues.

Comment: @i707107 Thanks for catching the typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove this question from the "unanswered" tab, here is a solution.

Let $v=(e^{i\theta},e^{2i\theta},\ldots,e^{in\theta})^\top$. Then $v^\top v=0$ and $A=\frac12\pmatrix{v&\bar{v}}\pmatrix{v^\top\\ \bar{v}^\top}$. Using the fact that $XY$ and $YX$ have identical nonzero eigenvalues, we see that the only two nonzero eigenvalues of $A$ are those of $\frac12\pmatrix{v^\top\\ \bar{v}^\top}\pmatrix{v&\bar{v}}=\frac12\pmatrix{0&n\\ n&0}$, i.e. $\pm\frac n2$. Hence $\det(I+A)=(1-\frac n2)(1+\frac n2)=1-\frac{n^2}4$.

Comment: (+1) Very nice! Especially using the fact that $XY$ and $YX$ have identical nonzero eigenvalues.